# Issue while refreshing token generated from Aadtokenprovider

Tags: azure-active-directory, token, chatbot, spfx-extension

I am using Aadtokenprovider in my spfx bot extension for generating token. After token get expired bot show error 'Unable to connect'. How do I refresh token and pass it .

Comment: Can you please give us more details about your Aadtokenprovider

Comment: this.context.aadTokenProviderFactory
       .getTokenProvider()
       .then((tokenProvider: AadTokenProvider): Promise<string> => {

         return tokenProvider.getToken('my client id ');
       }).then((accessToken: string): void => {
       
         console.log(accessToken);
       });

Comment: after expiration of token token provider get token is not resolving at all on calling again. tokenProvider.getToken('api://my client id');
"Promise {<pending>}"

Comment: This seems to be microsoft bug. https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/4892

Answer (score 0):

There is an open issue with Microsoft for this problem. [github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/4892](http://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/4892)